# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'

Tags: python, django

- I am implementing a likes system for my post. I have used a ManyToManyField in my model.
- `models.py`

```
class MarketingMaestro (models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    total_value = models.IntegerField()
    branding_video = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
```

- In this I get all the list of the users, and if someone likes the post it is updated in the field. But when I am trying to implement the logic where if the user has already liked the post he/she will be able to see the dislike button only.
- While doing so I am fetching all the values from the db and checking particular `likes` field but it is showing error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'`
- It is giving me error on the line

```
if marking_maestro.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
```

- I tried printing the value but is it returning just the queryset `<QuerySet [<MarketingMaestro: MarketingMaestro object (1)>]>` and if i print the `product_title` using `(marking_maestro.product_title)` but then I get the error saying `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'product_title'`
  -`views.py`

```
def brand(request):
    # fetching all the projects
    marking_maestro = MarketingMaestro.objects.all()
    is_liked = False
    print(marking_maestro)
    if marking_maestro.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True

    # fetching the votes
    emailID = request.user.email
    context = {
        'is_liked' : is_liked
    }

    return render(request, 'brand.html', {'marking_maestro' : marking_maestro}, context)
```

Comment: `marking_maestro` is not a *single* `MarketingMaestro` object, it is a *collection* (QuerySet) of `MarketingMaestro`s, so it makes no sense to work with `marking_maestro.likes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for performing queries like `marking_maestro.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():` or `marking_maestro.product_title` you need to first get an object of `MarketingMaestro`.

Here, only mistake you are doing is that, you are performing queries on `QuerySet` rather than `MarketingMaestro` object.

So what you need to do is

```
marking_maestro = MarketingMaestro.objects.first()
```

(here I've taken `first` to just illustrate the concept, you can take whatevet the object you want)

and then perform whatever the queries you want to.

Comment: A problem with using `.first()` is that it will return, well, the first object. That can be different each time. But even if it is always the same, we are not sure that this is the object we are interested in.